# Class library project Configuration with DbContext in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2019

I defined a class library project in for Data Access layer and it tries to create DbContext but I face an error like this:

> The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.

Which has inner execption:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

I face this error while `App.config` and Connection String exist. In fact the `App.config` would be created when I add **ADO.NET Entity Data Model**.

I work with visual studio 2019 and SQL Server 2022 and .NET Framework v 4.8.

I redefined connection string.

and also follow this:
[Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125429/how-do-you-define-dbcontext-properly-in-a-class-library-project)

But

```
builder.Services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<AppContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
```

doesn't exist for me!

Comment: Does your project use a Nuget reference to add the [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/)? Sounds like it might be a GAC reference that's not bundled with your deployment.

Comment: I tried to configure but I don't know what I should configure, because appsettings are empty for me.

Comment: I used Mirosoft Entity Framework Core instead and it works now.
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by recreating the project as ***empty class library*** and then installed packages **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore** and **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer** and run the below command in PMC:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=true;TrustServerCertificate=True; User Id=myuser; Password=mypassword;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```