# Unable to use "dotnet ef database update" in Blazor application

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-identity

I added a .NET Core Blazor project with authorization. The project is added with scaffolding files for migrations, register & login components, etc...

I tried to add the tables to SQL Server by running

```
dotnet ef database update
```

but I'm getting this error:

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[MyProject.Data.ApplicationDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'MyProject.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance.

This is my `ApplicationDbContext` class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>(options)
{
}
```

This is the Program.cs implementation

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

I couldn't find relevant results on google or here on SO. Am I missing something & how to fix it?

---

Edit: I thought there was issue in the scaffolded files & thus was unable to run the migration, so I created a new blazor project & this time, I was apple to run it. So the migration error was due to a change that I added but missed it when I was troubleshooting it.

In order to give a better understanding, I have multiple projects & I created a Class Library Project -**ClassLibrary1**- to hold the shared functionalities between these projects.

But as soon as I try to use the `ClassLibrary1.Data.ApplicationDbContext` in my blazor application -**BlazorApp1**-, I get the error.

Because there are multiple files, I created a simplified version of my solution. Kindly refer to the [repository](https://github.com/Ahmed-M-Yasser/core_multiple_projects_context_issue)

The error appears once I add `builder.Services.AddSingleton<SegmentService>();` to my `Program.cs`

I want to use `ApplicationDbContext` & `ApplicationUser` that exists in **ClassLibrary1**

Comment: Please show the implementation of the context in `program.cs`

Comment: Are you running the command from the client folder or server?

Comment: @BrianParker From the server folder where the Migrations folder exists

Comment: Is that your total context, an empty class? Not sure if that's your problem, but with an empty class, updating the database won't do anything. Tables are only created if you add `DbSet<T>` properties for them

Comment: Add the whole program. Did you register the builder? How did you make the DI?

Comment: have you installed the design package? `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="8.0.0" />`

Comment: by the way, does your solution contains several projects? if yes, could you pls try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69207083)? `dotnet ef database update --verbose --project CommandService.Data   --startup-project CommandService`. I mean you might define the project with command `--project `

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel No, that's not the complete context. I added more details in the question. Kindly check them, the issue now happens when I try to run the project. Migration & running the project completes successfully if I don't try to use the context from the class library project

Comment: @LeandroBardelli I added more details in the question & GIT repo to reproduce the issue

Comment: @TinyWang Yes, I installed it, it turned out that the migration is working fine. The issue happened because in Program.cs, I was trying to use the CLP context instead of the blazor context class

Comment: does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63614979) and [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34141061) help you? According to your sample, it looks like that you want to put DB handling method in class library, and then calling out of box methods in class library from main blazor project. Am I right?

Comment: I had a test in my side which using `builder.Services.AddScoped<SegmentService>();` instead. If I comment this line the app could run, if I used `AddSingleton` I would get 
 error like screenshot showed.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuY8O.png  and if I switch to use `AddScoped` then it run again..

Comment: @TinyWang Yes, you understood what I want to do correctly. I tried AddScoped but got the same error. If you are able to run it successfully after registering SegmentService, please add it as answer down & highlight your other changes. I also checked the links that you provided but still no luck with it

Comment: do you have any update on this question now? @Ahmed

Comment: @TinyWang Still no luck with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `SegmentService` we inject `private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;` so that we use `builder.Services.AddSingleton<SegmentService>();` should be correct. I checked your project and reproduced your error.

[image]

That's because you also had many other services such as `builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityUserAccessor>();` which is based on `ApplicationDbContext` you defined in the blazor project but not the one you defined in Class Library. If I used ApplicationDbContext in Class Library, I would get error like below:

[image]

So my idea is that we could continue to use `ApplicationDbContext` you defined in the blazor project, and let's change the `ISegmentService` to use `Task<IEnumerable<Segment>> GetSegmentsAsync(int? id, ApplicationDbContext dbcontext);`, then we could set ApplicationDbContext as a parameter when calling the methods defining in Class Library.

====================================

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<SegmentService>(); //causes error
    
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ClassLibrary1.Data.ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
```

Comment: I thought of this but I don't think it's the correct way because I want to consume the method inside SegmentService in Blazor component, so as far as I know, I don't have access to ApplicationDbContext there. Please refer to BlazorApp1.Components.Home.razor

Comment: then can we only use a single ApplicationDbContext? I mean all the ApplicationDbContext are refer to ClassLibrary1.Data.ApplicationDbContext  ?

Comment: I also had another test that, since you both have applicationdbcontext in class library and main project, to solve the exception for injecting `SegmentService`, we should make sure that the  `ClassLibrary1.Data.ApplicationDbContext` is also injected in the main blazor project so that when we inject `SegmentService`, we could have  `ClassLibrary1.Data.ApplicationDbContext` for it to avoid the exception. I added code  snippet in my post and you may refer to it.

Comment: I tried using the class library context earlier but it also gave me error. I see you added both contexts. The project built successfully but it gave another error => The entity type 'IdentityUserRole<string>' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'

Comment: The new error is fixed by adding `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` to `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)`. Thanks a lot @TinyWang. It's working now

Answer (score 0):

The error mentioned in the question was caused by me, but I wasn't aware of it at the time of asking the question. I created a new Blazor project & tried it right away & it worked without issues.

Then, I faced another error -mentioned above by @TinyWang-

> Some services are not able to be constructed

because I was trying to use the context from the Class Library Project in the Blazor app. To make a long story short, it only worked thanks to @TinyWang's help after doing 3 changes.

1.Adding **both** contexts to **Program.cs** of the Blazor projet

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ClassLibrary1.Data.ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

2.Using `AddDbContextFactory` instead of `AddDbContext`

3.Adding the below line to `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` in **ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

Lastly, this is a [helpful read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to understand more about context in Blazor applications.